# Android Service to store Sim Card serial

Tags: java, android, service

i have a service to get Current Sim Serial and detect whether second sim card is inserted. So i would like to store the first sim card when the service run, Does anyone can tell me which way i can use to store integer value(sim serial).

When the second sim card inserted(after device reboot), i would like to compare the stored sim and current sim, if so detected then do something.

So basically i just want to write a sim card value to storage.

Answer (score 0):

For store integer value(sim serial) You Should Use Android **Preferences** .

For More Refer these Links

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html
2. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/
3. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really are in for security id rather suggest using a PaaS like heroku and using your own web application to store that. Anyone can just erase the data from your application and have it think it is its first time running,